# Convert all columns of datetime to different date format in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I currently have a table, where three columns, named Start_Time, End_Time, and Scheduled_Time all have data format of Datetime where the format is YYYY-MM-DD 12:00:00 (24 hour clock). How would I be able to convert these columns where it would display as MM-DD_YYYY 12:00:00 (AM/PM) clock?

Comment: you don't. mysql internal timestamps are always in 24hour format. what you have is a display issue. do the am/pm conversion in your client-side code when it comes time to display those timestamps, or at least do the conversion with `select date_format(datefield, '...')`

Comment: Is there any way where I can just have MM-DD-YYYY with a 24 hour clock?

Comment: use a `date` type instead of `datetime`, or `select date(timestampfield)` to get just the `yyyy-mm-dd` bit

Comment: thanks, but I need the actual time aspect also. And my main goal is to have it display mm-dd-yyyy with the time.

Comment: then do the am/pm stuff in your display code. you never mess with the db's internal formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that if you have a table with a column such as datefield DATETIME, in your select statement, if you CAST(datefield AS VARCHAR(20)), this will give you the proper time you are looking for(AM, and PM)

Testing it out myself I went from datefield being 2014-07-30 16:44:00 to Jul 30 2014 4:44PM by using CAST()